# calculate all sequences of tic tac toe

Tags: java, pseudocode

I'm trying to calculate all the sequences for a tic tac toe game.  We assume X's go first and are designated with a 1 and O's always go second and are designated with a -1. Empty cells are designated with 0.  We have an array of 9 that holds the current board position.  I'm trying to calculate all the possible board positions and place them in an ArrayList<int[]> where the size of each element is 9.  Let's assume we have a board of size 3 for illustrative purposes.

Possible boards:

```
 0  0  0
 1  0  0    0  1  0    0  0  1
 1 -1  0   -1  1  0   -1  0  1
 1 -1  1   -1  1  1   -1  1  1x
 1  0 -1    0  1 -1    0 -1  1
 1  1 -1    1  1 -1x   1 -1  1x
```

boards noted with an x are duplicates.

I can't for the life me figure out how to generate this list with or without duplicates.  I tried to list the boards out in the order I think they would be produced if we were using nested loops (In this case 3).

I'm not looking for code but rather help with pseudo code on how to do this.

Comment: I don't understand what the possible boards are supposed to be. Shouldn't they be 3x3?

Comment: yes the actual problem will have an array of 9 for each board.  I use 3 here as an example because using 9 generates too many possible boards for me to list

Comment: @user16320675 not true since the number of 1s always equals to the number of -1s or bigger in 1. some of the states are not valid

Comment: @user16320675 read the questions again.  there are 362,880 possible boards

Comment: Do you only want valid boards?  For example, you could never have more than 5 1s or -1s in one of your arrays.  Do the arrays all represent the placement of the Xs and Os?  If so, then assume that your array indices from 0-8 represent the top left, top center, top right, middle left, middle center, etc. - in that case the following would be invalid:  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1 (because it would represent Xs winning horizontally in the top row, and Os winning horizontally in the bottom row, which is impossible).   A lot more clarification is needed for what is or is not a valid board.

Comment: @jer, the problem is clearly stated.  all boards with or without duplicates are fine.  The boards need to be generated by placing 1 followed by a -1  until the array element  is filled.  as a number is added to the element it is added to the arraylist

Comment: @user16320675 there are 9 ways to place a 1 on an empty board.  There are 8 ways to place a -1 once X has gone.  There are now 7 ways to place X's second move -> 9! = 362880.  Also read the question it clearly states I'm trying to calculate all the sequences for a tic tac toe game.

Comment: no I am not.  read the question

Comment: I am not at all convinced by your 362880 calculation, as I don't believe it excludes examples like the one I gave above (1,1,1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1).   Also, your 3-square board is not a good example - how many does X or O need to get in a row to win?  1?  2?  Square numbers (where the number of consecutive pieces needed to win is the square root of the board size) are the only reasonable choice if you want a good analogy with a normal 9-square board.   To ask a concrete question:  on a 4-square board, do you consider the sequence [1, 1, -1, -1] to be valid?